# How can we change the path of "modules" folder in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii

the default path of the modules folder in yii framework is like this

`Yii project -> protected -> modules`

but i need to move "modules" folders outside the Yii project, so the new path should be like this

`Yii project -> protected`

`modules` (this folder is outside yii project)

how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it in your yii configuration file, ie:

```
// .... Other configuration options...

// Set module path:
'modulePath' => 'some/path',
'modules' => array(
    // .... Your modules configuration
)
```